# CKEditor: width of buttons

Tags: ckeditor

I need to reduce the width of the following buttons (drop-downs):

- "Formatting Styles"
- "Paragraph Format"
- "Font Name"
- "Font Size"

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the CSS of the underlying button element.

If you want to target specific tools, just use firebug to dig into the DOM and see what their particular classes are.

For example, to modify the widths of the format and font drop downs, use the following CSS:

```
.cke_skin_kama .cke_format .cke_text,
.cke_skin_kama .cke_font .cke_text {
    width: 72px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CKEditor 4, you can adjust `.cke_combo_text` like this:

```
span.cke_combo_text {
  width: 30px;
}
```

Note that if you make it smaller than the default (60px for Formatting Styles), then when the user selects an option from the dropdown, the selected option will no longer fit inside the updated dropdown box.

In my case, I was looking to clean up the UI so that it all fits into one line neatly on an iPhone in vertical orientation, so I did this:

```
span.cke_combo_text {
  width: inherit;
}
```

For my case, this was great because it shrinks the dropdown menu so that it fits on one line by default, but automatically expands (taking up a new line) if an option is selected, showing the user what they chose.